# Trouble installing packages with Yarn due to SSL certificate error

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, hadoop-yarn

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install packages using Yarn in my Node.js project. Whenever I run the yarn add command to install a package, I get the following error:

lua
Copy code
error Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
I've tried troubleshooting the issue by checking my network connection, updating Yarn and Node.js to the latest versions, and ensuring that my firewall and antivirus settings are not interfering with the network connection. However, the error persists.

I'm not sure what else to try to resolve this issue. Can anyone suggest further troubleshooting steps or potential solutions to fix this SSL certificate error with Yarn?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!